# giving hollow objects a thickness

Tags: modeling

I'm working on a uh60 Blackhawk. The problem is I need to give the main body a thickness. Extruding gives the object different thicknesses at different points.  I want it to have the same thickness across all of the body. So for example, I might want to have a thickness of 5cm that is maintained for the entire body.

Here is a picture of what I want to make, that needs a thickness that is maintained throughout the main body:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use Solidify modifier.